# reverse a number in python looking for debugging

Tags: python, reverse

Hi I have the code for reversing a number, I am a beginner for python?

I dont know why is not working, thanks for your help.

```
class Solution(object):
    def revint(self, number):
        while(number>0)：
            reverse=0
            reminder=0
            reverse=(reverse*10)+reminder
            number=number//10 
        return reverse
revint(123)
```

Comment: First obivous thing is you did not create an instance. So, `Solution().revint(123)` instead. Also, make sure (in the future also) to explicitly provide what is the error you get. preferably Include the Stacktrace.

Comment: You're setting `reverse` (and `reminder`—"remainder"?) to 0 each time through the loop. So, you add another digit to `reverse`, then you throw that away and go back to 0, over and over. So you're only going to end up with the last digit. And even that won't be right, because it will be adding `0` as the remainder instead of the actual remainder from the last `number // 10`, because you don't do anything to calculate it.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply:

```
def revint(number):
    return int(str(number)[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is here:

```
revint(123)
```

There is no `revint` function to call. You've defined a `revint` *method*, on the `Solution` class. So, you need to construct an instance, so you can call its methods:

```
solution = Solution()
solution.revint(123)
```

You also need to do something with the result of that method, not just ignore it:

```
print(solution.revint(123))
```

---

Next:

```
    while(number>0)：
        reverse=0
```

You're resetting `reverse` to 0 each time through the loop. So, you add a digit, then throw it away and start at 0 again, then add another digit, and so on. So you're going to end up with just the last digit.

You only way to set it to 0 once, at the start:

```
    reverse=0
    while(number>0)：
```

---

Next:

```
    reminder = 0
```

This is apparently supposed to be the remainder of dividing `number` by `10`. But if you want that, you have to say so. Either:

```
    remainder = number % 10
```

… or, together with the division:

```
    number, remainder = divmod(number, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have initiated a variable **reverse=0** in side while loop,
>   so the variable is not reachable to return statement.

```
def reverse_a_number(number: int) -> int:
    reverse = 0
    while number > 0:
        remainder = number % 10
        reverse = (reverse * 10) + remainder
        number = number // 10
    return reverse



rev = reverse_a_number(123456)
print(rev)
```

**Output:**

654321